# Read Gimp's XCF image file in Java

Tags: java, bufferedimage, gimp, xcf

Is there a Java library that can read `XCF` image format (`GIMP` native file format), i.e. into `BufferedImage`?
I know there is a linux script `xcf2png` or `xcf2jpg`. Is it possible to read directly from Java?

Comment: Read what, the individual layers, masks and channels, or the composite image?

Comment: I don't think such a library exists, but I would be very interested to create an XCF ImageIO plugin for Java, given the time and resources to do so.

Comment: Optimally to read individual layers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no available library that can read or parse XCF file. If you don't want to convert it in the first place, you should be implementing your own parser, using https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gimp/blob/master/devel-docs/xcf.txt